# How to specify function parameter in class

Tags: dart

How do I do something like this (`getNames`)?

```dart
class APIServer {
  String name;
  Future<String> getNames(String query);
  APIServer({this.name, this.function});
}
```

Comment: I don't follow. Could you describe what you want to have happen as a result?

Comment: VSCode says that it isn't a abstract class, so I can't do it (?) — `'getNames' must have a method body because 'APIServer' isn't abstract.
Try making 'APIServer' abstract, or adding a body to 'getNames'
`

Comment: The way you have `getNames` set up right now is as an abstract method, and you're getting that error because `APIServer` isn't an abstract class. What are you _trying_ to do?

Comment: I'm trying to say "Hey, do you want to create a new APIServer? Ok, give me a name and _a function that returns a Future<String> and recieves a 'String query' parameter_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `Function` type to declare a function variable.

```
class APIServer {
  String name;
  Future<String> Function(String query) getNames;

  APIServer({this.name, this.getNames});
}
```

Alternatively, create a `typedef` signature to tie the function signature to a data type:

```
typedef NameGetter = Future<String> Function(String query);

class APIServer {
  String name;
  NameGetter getNames;

  APIServer({this.name, this.getNames});
}
```